# What are the format characters using in log4j and explain their usage and give me some example?

Tags: log4j, log4jdbc

I have the below entry in the log4j config xml. What is the significant of '%p', '%C;%L', '%m'.  What is stands for those characters? What other characters, we can use in log4j? Explain their usage..

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" 
value="INSERT INTO LOGS (user_id, dated, msg_level, class, message) 
       VALUES ( '%X{MESSAGE_ID}','%d{ISO8601}','%p', '%C;%L', '%m' )" />
</layout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the main conversion characters are

> > p  --- Used to output the priority of the logging event.
> >
> > C --- Used to output the fully qualified class name of the caller issuing the logging request.
> >
> > L --- Used to output the line number from where the logging request was issued.
> >
> > m  --- Used to output the application supplied message associated with the logging event.

Using number with any conversion character, for example `%4p` means

> > the priority of the logging event should be left justified to a width of four characters.

Besides this conversions , there are other patterns also .
You can see detail about them [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).